# Command to display previous,current,next month of Cal of year 2015 dec

Tags: linux, command, remote, calendar

I know how to display the previous, current ,next Month of ongoing current month .but I didn't know for the particular year mentioned...what is the command used in Unix to get the output

Answer (score 4):

```
$ cal -A1 -B1 12 2015
   November 2015         December 2015          January 2016      
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7         1  2  3  4  5                  1  2  
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14   6  7  8  9 10 11 12   3  4  5  6  7  8  9  
15 16 17 18 19 20 21  13 14 15 16 17 18 19  10 11 12 13 14 15 16  
22 23 24 25 26 27 28  20 21 22 23 24 25 26  17 18 19 20 21 22 23  
29 30                 27 28 29 30 31        24 25 26 27 28 29 30  
                                            31
```

Comment: That is BSD cal, I assume, since GNU cal errors out with `cal: invalid option -- 'A'`

Comment: It is FreeBSD `ncal`, which is also [the `cal` in Debian 10](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/bsdmainutils/cal.1.en.html).